# Java RGBA bufferedimage to GIF bufferedimage

Tags: java, gif, bufferedimage, rbga

Need function that converts Java RGB bufferedimage to GIF bufferedimage but with colormap that is bigger than 256 colors.

Does anybody know if there are exist such library or a self-written function?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> ..with colormap that is bigger than 256 colors.

No can do.  GIF supports a ***maximum*** of 256 colors.  Use PNG instead.

So to answer your specific question..

> Does anybody know if there are exist such library or a self-written function?

No it doesn't exist.